# The degree of a polynomial which also has negative exponents.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, definition, laurent-series

In theory, we define the degree of a polynomial as the highest exponent it holds.

However when there are negative and positive exponents are present in the function, I want to know the basis that we define the degree.  Is the order of a polynomial degree expression defined by the highest **magnitude** of available exponents?

For example in $x^{-4} + x^{3}$, is the degree $4$ or $3$?

Comment: A polynomial only contains positive, integral indices. So $x^{-4}+x^{3}$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: A polynomial has only positive exponents. The degree of a rational function, that is a quotient of two polynomials, in your case $(x^7 + 1)/x^4$ is usually defined as the difference of the degrees of the involved polynomials.

Comment: @Shaktal : Thanks for adding the proper editing tags.

Comment: @martini : Thank you for guiding to the correct definition. So the expression I have is a rational function. If the resulting expression of the difference of a rational function is polynomial then degree can be found using polynomial exponential rule. In my case, the difference is resulting in a rational function. Can I say the degree is 3 in that case? Because upper degree of numerator is 7, upper degree of denominator is 4, the difference is 3...

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes.

Comment: @martini Hi I want to vote you, but not sure how to do so. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: If you are referring to [Laurent polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) then some authors do speak of their degree (and also their order as as [Laurent power series)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)

Comment: @BillDubuque appreciate your input. Before posting this question I did a search and found out that Laurent polynomials have both positive, negative exponents. However it wasn't the level I was searching for. The indepth analysis of Laurent is a little beyond the 'freedom' allowed in my question at this point. But as I am interested in reading, I will do in due time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In abstract algebra, we write the set of all polynomials with coefficients in a ring $R$ as $R[x]$.
Here "polynomials" means expressions of the form $$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots +a_nx^n$$ where $a_0,\ldots,a_n\in R$ and $n$ is finite (Note: if you don't know what a ring is, just think of the $a$'s as numbers). So, in this context, your expression $x^{-4}+x^3$ isn't in a polynomial, because all the powers of $x$ have to be non-negative.

We can generalize this construction, though.  The first thing we can do is drop the requirement that $n$ must be finite.  If we do this, we get $R[[x]]$, the set of *formal power series* in $R$.

A futher generalization is the set of *formal Laurent series* in $R$, denoted $R(\hspace{-0.5pt}(x)\hspace{-0.5pt})$, and this is a setting in which we can answer your question.  Formal Laurent series have the form 
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}a_nx^n$$ 
where $a_n=0$ for all but finitely many negative $n$.  In other words, formal Laurent series are formal power series which are allowed to have a finite number of negative exponents too.

The *order* of a formal Laurent series is defined as the smallest $n$ such that $a_n\not= 0$.  This is kind of like the degree of a polynomial, but for negative integers.  The *degree* of a formal Laurent series is defined in the same way as the degree of a polynomial, though the degree may not exist (since all of the $a_n$ for $n>0$ are still allowed to be nonzero).

So, considered as a formal Laurent series, we would say that $x^{-4}+x^3$ has degree $3$ and order $-4$.

Comment: Then what is the degree of $ \dfrac 1x$, as a polynomial (or monomial) in $ x$? Again if this is not a polynomial in $ x$, then why do we write $ f(x)= \dfrac 1x$?

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to add that this generalization of polynomials is called a [Laurent polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial). This set is denoted $R[x,x^{-1}]$.

Comment: Thanks, this is surely a more natural setting than a Laurent series.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is essentially: how does one define the degree of a Laurent polynomial?

My guess is that the best of of doing this is to move from degrees to "degree pairs." Let me explain this for polynomials first.

Given a polynomial $$P(x) = \sum_{n:\mathbb{N}} a_n x^n,$$ define the degree pair of $P$ to be the pair $(i,j)$ where $i$ is the least natural number such that $a_i$ is non-zero, and $a_j$ is the greatest natural number such that $a_j$ is non-zero. Denote this $\mathrm{dpa}(P)$. For example:

$$\mathrm{dpa}(-3x^5+x^2+x) = (1,5)$$

This extends straightforwardly to Laurent polynomials, and seems to be relatively well-behaved.