# Are Laurent series called polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, laurent-series

Traditionally, polynomials cannot have negative exponents. So what gives? Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574001/why-cant-polynomials-have-negative-exponents-or-division-by-a-variable).

Comment: Laurent series with only finitely many nonzero terms are called *Laurent polynomials*.  *Laurent* polynomials are not necessarily polynomials.  Despite that, the word polynomial appearing in the name still suggests a great deal about the structure.

Comment: I see, so it's just standard nomenclature being context specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a polynomial has only *nonnegative* powers of its variables, while Laurent series have *some* powers of negative degree. Thus Laurent series and polynomials are disjoint.

If, however, there are only finitely many positive and negative powers in a Laurent series, it may be called a *Laurent polynomial*.

Answer (score 2):

A [Laurent polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) is an expression of the form $p(x,x^{-1})$, where $p$ is a polynomial in two variables.

A Laurent polynomial is a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) with only finitely many terms.