# Why is raising a polynomial to some power of a fraction not an allowed operation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm reading Gelfand's *Algebra* and it says that the legal operations for polynomials are addition, subtractions and multiplication but taking the square root (i.e. raising the polynomial to the power of $2$) is not a legal operation.

I understood why division (and therefore negative exponents) are not allowed operations [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574001/why-cant-polynomials-have-negative-exponents-or-division-by-a-variable) but I don't see the 'harm' on allowing raising the polynomials to the power of $ n $

Why is this?

[image]

Comment: What about raising to fractional powers? Do we get a polynomial back in general?

Comment: There is no harm, but there is also no need; that operation can be expressed in terms of multiplication. But note that multiplication of polynomials _can't_ be expressed in terms of addition, so you need to take both of those operations as fundamental. Can you see where the difference comes from?

Comment: **Positive integer** powers can be expressed in term of multiplication.  The question seems to be about fractional powers (or does the OP really think that $\sqrt{x} = x^2$?)

Comment: I edited the question adding the relevant piece of text of the book The problem is with doing $ a - b = (\sqrt{a})^2 - (\sqrt{b})^2 $

Comment: You may want to be clearer about what you mean by 'raising to the power of $n$'; there's a wide gap between 'raising to the power of $5$', say, and 'raising to the power of $1/3$'.

Comment: @Jon That statement is correct; $a-b=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$ _is_ a valid factorization of $a-b$. But it's not a _polynomial_ factorization, because neither factor is a polynomial.

Comment: As a polynomial, we have $a,b\in\Bbb R$.  But in that other form, you must assume $a,b\geq0$.

Comment: @AndrewChin Be careful; polynomials can be defined over abstract structures as well. $a-b$ (as a polynomial in $a$ and $b$) is well-defined in many different domains.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki So the issue here is that the result is not a polynomial because of the fractional exponent (and polynomials only allow positive integers)? Not that raising to the power of a fraction is not allowed?

Comment: @Jon Raising to the power of a fraction _isn't_ allowed; but raising to the power of an integer _is_.

Comment: Taking the square root **is not** the same as raising the polynomial to the power of $2$, but to the power of $1/2$. Raising a polynomial to a non-negative integer power is allowed, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The *is* no harm. Remember that, if $n\in\mathbb N$ and $P(x)$ is a poynomial, then$$P(x)^n=\overbrace{P(x)\times P(x)\times\cdots\times p(x)}^{\phantom{\text{ times}}n\text{ times}}.$$So, since multiplication is allowed, raising a polynomial to a natural exponent is also allowed.

Comment: This makes sense to me so I'm assuming I didn't phrase the question properly. I edited the question adding the relevant piece of text of the book

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the key notion of abstraction (sometimes aka 'formality') behind polynomials. Suppose that we say 'a polynomial (in one variable) over some base structure is *formally* an expression of the form  $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n_P} p_ix^i$, where $n_P$ is some non-negative integer (so that the notion of summing makes sense) and each $p_i$ is a 'scalar' (i.e., an element of our base structure). Then we can define an addition operation on polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ by *defining* the polynomial $R(x)=\{P+Q\}(x)$ such that $n_R=\max(n_P, n_Q)$ and $r_i=p_i+q_i$ for all $i\leq n_R$ (where any potentially undefined $p_i$ or $q_i$ are taken to be zero). Note that for this definition to make sense, we need to have an addition defined on our base structure, but that's *all* we need for this formal definition to make sense!*

Similarly, we can *formally* define the product of two polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ by *defining* the polynomial $R(x)=\{P\cdot Q\}(x)$ such that $n_R=n_P+n_Q$ and $r_i=\sum_{j=0}^i p_jq_{i-j}$ for all $i\leq n_R$ (again taking potentially undefined coefficients as zero). For *this* definition to make sense, we need to have some sort of multiplication defined on our base structure, but again that's all we need for the formal definition to make sense; as long as we have a 'base structure' with commutative addition and (not necessarily commutative!) multiplication, we can define these formal polynomial-things over that structure, and they *also* have (commutative) addition and a well-defined multiplication.

Now, there's *also* an 'evaluation map' that comes with each polynomial; if we call our base structure $B$, then for each polynomial $P(x)$ we can define a *function* $P^*:B\mapsto B$ by $P^*(b)=\sum_{i=0}^{n_P} p_ib^i$, where we use the multiplication in the base structure to compute the $b^i$ and then the product $p_ib^i$, and the addition in the base structure to compute the sum. This function can be very useful, but it's not the only thing we care about with polynomials; often we really only care about the polynomial as a *formal* entity!

We can talk about other algebraic structures than polynomials, and of course other functions. But one of the great benefits of polynomials is that all we need on the base structure is addition and multiplication, and they give us a new structure that *also* has addition and multiplication. For instance, I only defined polynomials in one variable above — but we can think of a polynomial in two variables $x,y$ as a polynomial in $y$ whose coefficients are each polynomials in $x$: $P(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^{n_P}P_i(x)y^i$.

Often in mathematics, the key to abstraction is to see how small the minimal set of requirements placed on a structure can be in order to do 'interesting' things with it. The idea of a *group*, for instance, can be motivated by starting with the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and noticing that the addition operation, all by itself, satisfies some interesting properties (it has an identity and it has inverses), and asking what we can say about structures where all we require is those properties, plus the basic rules we'd like them to obey. Because the requirements are so low, they can be met by things that look nothing like numbers — for instance, the set of symmetries of a dodecahedron.

Polynomials require a little more from the base structure, but the requirements are still small enough that we can apply them to all sorts of interesting structures that aren't just $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$).

$$ $$

*For simplicity's sake, we really want commutativity of addition or else we can't necessarily 'force' the ordering of the sum so that it makes sense.

Comment: Why the downvote?