# Laurent polynomial regression?

Tags: polynomials, laurent-series

Polynomial regression is a common way of doing curvilinear regression.  It is common to also use the inverse transform x^-1 (http://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=8&n=6).

One can extend the concept of the inverse transform by thinking about Laurent polynomials.

My question is do some practitioners use Laurent polynomial regression? What are the general "rules" around them?  With regular polynomials one tends to get a hill or a valley for each additional power.

I read this post which got me thinking about it:
[The degree of a polynomial which also has negative exponents.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231357/the-degree-of-a-polynomial-which-also-has-negative-exponents)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial

Example R code:

```
x=runif(100,2,10)/2
y=jitter(1+abs(cos(x)))
df=data.frame(x=x,y=y)
df=df[order(df$x),]
plot(df$x,df$y)
lines(df$x,predict(lm(y~x+I(x^2)+I(x^3),df)))
title("3rd degree poly");

plot(df$x,df$y)
lines(df$x,predict(lm(y~x+I(x^-1)+I(x^-2),df)))
title("Laurent poly");
```

Comment: stats.stackexchange.com might provide a better answer to this question than what you can get here.

Comment: OK I cross posted it over there...